# Examples of multiple binary packages

Tags: ppa, compiling, packaging, deb, inkscape

I'm trying to include a preview of the new experimental Gtk+ 3 build of Inkscape in [our PPA](https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/trunk)... I want to compile the upstream source using different compile-time options to generate two different binary packages: "inkscape-trunk" (the normal daily build) and "inkscape-trunk-gtk3" (the experimental Gtk+ 3 build).

Below, I've shown how I'd do this manually using the upstream source but I need to know how to do it using Debian packaging tools.

I already found the [mpb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpb) and [vim](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim) Ubuntu source packages, which both create multiple binaries using different compile-time configurations.  However, both of these use old debhelper syntax, and the rules files both end up being rather complex.

My question: Can anyone suggest a suitable example package, in which multiple binary builds are performed using the new elegant "dh" debhelper syntax?  Is this even possible, or do I have to resort to writing the rules file manually.

```bsh
# Building two different configurations of the same package...

# Make subfolders for building the two different configurations
src_dir=`pwd`
build_default_dir=${src_dir}/build-default
build_gtk3_dir=${src_dir}/build-gtk3
mkdir -p $build_default_dir
mkdir -p $build_gtk3_dir

# Generate build files
./autogen.sh

# Configure and build the default version
cd $build_default_dir
../configure --prefix=/usr/
make

# Configure and build the gtk+ 3 version
cd $build_gtk3_dir
../configure --prefix=/usr/ --enable-gtk3-experimental
make
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [qbittorrent](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/qbittorrent.git;a=blob;f=debian/rules;h=e98e77345b364ad0cff999fadf787e77c5a0e2ce;hb=HEAD) package, it builds two versions of the package from the same source using the new `dh` syntax. Here's what it might look like in your case (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    mkdir -p build-nox && cd build-default && ../configure --prefix=/usr
    mkdir -p build-gtk3 && cd build-gtk3 && ../configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gtk3-experimental

override_dh_auto_build:
    dh_auto_build --builddirectory build-default
    dh_auto_build --builddirectory build-gtk3

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install --builddirectory build-default --destdir debian/inkscape-trunk
    dh_auto_install --builddirectory build-gtk3 --destdir debian/inkscape-trunk-gtk3

override_dh_auto_clean:
    dh_auto_clean --builddirectory build-default
    dh_auto_clean --builddirectory build-gtk3
```

Comment: This looks great... the `--builddirectory` flag looks very useful.  A couple of minor points that come to mind:

 1. I need to run autogen.sh to generate build files for the PPA - easily done in the override_dh_auto_configure rule
 2. Is there a reason why we couldn't use `dh_auto_configure --builddirectory -- --enable-whatever` in the `override_dh_auto_configure` rule?
 3. There will be quite a lot of redundancy here... for example, all the tutorial files, icons etc will be identical for each build.  I guess it would be nice to have a shared inkscape-trunk-data package for both configs

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to say `dh_auto_configure --builddirectory build-gtk3 -- --enable-gtk3-experimental` (for example).

Comment: `dh_auto_configure --builddirectory build-gtk3 -- --enable-gtk3-experimental` should work as well. I was just basing this on `qbittorrent`'s approach as it's a package I've touch. I'm not sure why the maintainer made that choice.

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply.  I've finally sorted it.  I had to make a couple of minor changes, but it's almost exactly how you suggested.  See the [rules file in the repo](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/debian-packaging/view/head:/rules).  Many thanks for your great answer.